# How to query using a combination of custom_field values?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I need to get posts pertaining to a given category, AND :

- have the event_start_date (custom field) greater or equal than today's date
- OR have a event_end date (custom field) greater or equal than today (if their event_start_date date is less than today's date

The results need to be order using the custom_start field.

I'm working on this code, but I cannot find the relevant documentation for this specific usecase. Can you help, either pointing me to a good online explanation, or explain me how to fix my query?

```
    $since = date('Y-m-d');
    $args = array(
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date_start_id',
    'category_name'     => 'private',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            //event_date_start_id greater or equal to $since
            'key' => 'bjab_event_date_start_id',
            'value' => $since,
            'type' => 'numeric',
             'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
             //event_date_end_id greater or equal to $since
             //and event_date_start_id lower than $since
             // and event_date_start_id != ""
            'relation' => 'AND',
             array(
                'key' => 'bjab_event_date_start_id',
                'value' => $since,
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '<'
             ),
             array(
                'key' => 'bjab_event_date_end_id',
                'value' => $since,
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
             array(
                'key' => 'bjab_event_date_end_id',
                'value' => '',
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    )
);

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WordPress 4.1 it is possible to build nested [meta, date and tax queries](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/). I've not tested it but the code bellow should work. Also, I recommend to replace PHP `date()` function with [`current_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) from WordPress to get the current date taking in account the blog time zone configuration:

After the chat with you, it seems that you just need to use "DATE" as `type` argument.

```
$since = current_time('Y-m-d');
$args = array(
        'meta_key'          => 'bjab_event_date_start_id',
        'category_name'     => 'private',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                //event_date_start_id greater or equal to $since
                'key' => 'bjab_event_date_start_id',
                'value' => $since,
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'bjab_event_date_end_id',
                'value' => $since,
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I've updated to 4.1 and tried your suggestion: it shows all posts (not only those in the category "private"). Why is that? I tried also specifying the category as part of each meta value array. Thanks a lot for current_time(), i was unaware of its existence!

Comment: That is strange. Adding a `meta_query` shouldn't affect to category parameter. Check that the category slug is correct and try with and without the `meta_query`. And it is not a good idea include category or any other non-meta query arguments in the `meta_query` array.

Comment: sorry, my mistake: category is fine. Still, the parameters don't seem to matter: all posts in category are displayed, no matter the event_date_start or _end value. I'll update my question with the current code.

Comment: I think the problem may occur because many posts do not have any event_end_date_id set. I guess the comparison accepts to consider that today >= ''

Comment: I have updated my question with the current code, in which I tried to address the case where event_end_date_id is empty. No dice: i don't get any result anymore. I'm really having a hard time understanding this syntax.

Comment: Maybe you can include a nested meta query with `NOT EXISTS` as comparison parameter. I will edit the answer in a moment with an example.

Comment: Wait. If a post has not `event_end_date_id` set, how do you want to handle it? Please, think again about the date conditionals and think about any possible scenarios. In your last question update your code says: "retur post with `bjab_event_date_start_id < today` AND `event_end_date_id <= today` AND `event_end_date_id != ""`; that obviously doesn't match, `event_end_date_id` can not be `<= today` and `!= ""` at the same time. See my suggestion with "NOT EXIST".

Comment: Sorry for my unclear comment, i'll fix it immediatly. To be clear: if a post has no event_end_date_id set, either its event_start_date_id is past, so it should not be selected, or is upcoming/current, in which case it should be selected.

Comment: Also, can you post the date format on your custom field? I think you are not using it corretly. You are trying to compare numeric values but you are using "Y-m-d" date format. Not sure if I don't see the meta field code.

Comment: See edited answer. It should return posts with `bjab_event_date_start_id >= today` (not matter which bjab_event_date_end_id it has; it is upcoming event or current if = today) OR posts with `bjab_event_date_start_id < today AND bjab_event_date_end_id EXISTS (is set) AND >= today` (it has a start date in the past and a end date in the future). Note that I need the meta field code because I think the data format for date can not be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19701/discussion-between-pixeline-and-cybmeta).