# What's the best way to query for currently running Wordpress events

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query

I have a custom post type 'events' which has two extra fields. start_date and end_date.

Start date must be set but end date is optional. I want to show events that are upcoming (after today's date) or currently running (so today's date would be past the start_date but still before the end date)

I want to order the results by the start date. I have something like:

```
$args = array(

    'post_type'        => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'   => 100,
    'meta_key'       => 'start_event',
    'meta_value'     => date("Y-m-d"),
    'meta_compare'   => '>=',
    'meta_type'     => 'DATE',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'ASC',

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',

              array(
               'key' => 'end_event',
               'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
               'compare' => '>=',
               'type' => 'DATE'
            ),

        )

   );

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This does not seem to take into account the meta query and only shows events with a start_date >= today and does not include events with end_date >= today if the start date has passed.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Additionally to possible duplicate question, you are comparing exactly with today date, note your use of `date("Y-m-d")`.

Comment: Not a duplicate - that is searching for events BETWEEN two dates - I am looking to get events AFTER todays date. And yes, I am comparing exactly with todays date. I basically want to get events with start_date OR end_date after today.

Comment: Also I need to order by start_date - that is important - I can get the required results by putting both start_date and end_date in the meta_query however the ordering is then incorrect.

Comment: See [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173100/how-to-query-using-a-combination-of-custom-field-values/173102#173102). I think it is exactly the same issue.